# MS Excel Plots not displaying correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

This was originally asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697034/ms-excel-plots-not-displaying-correctly) but has been voted for closure and moved to this site.

I have a dataset in excel like the following (starting at cell A1 going to D100)

```
|  Part  |  MK_CREATED_DT  | ORD_NUM | LINE_NUM |
|:------:|:---------------:|:-------:|:--------:|
| DEW361 | 10/17/2018 0:00 |  ABC410 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/11/2018 0:00 |  ABC318 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  2/7/2019 0:00  |  ABC391 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  2/13/2019 0:00 |  ABC323 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  2/18/2019 0:00 |  ABC320 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  2/18/2019 0:00 |  ABC490 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  2/28/2019 0:00 |  ABC428 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  2/28/2019 0:00 |  ABC364 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  7/11/2019 0:00 |  ABC482 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  4/11/2019 0:00 |  ABC418 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/4/2018 0:00  |  ABC448 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/17/2018 0:00 |  ABC498 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/18/2018 0:00 |  ABC446 |     1    |
| DEW361 | 11/24/2018 0:00 |  ABC477 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  12/3/2018 0:00 |  ABC394 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  12/3/2018 0:00 |  ABC397 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  12/3/2018 0:00 |  ABC318 |     3    |
| DEW361 |  1/7/2019 0:00  |  ABC444 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  1/31/2019 0:00 |  ABC380 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  1/31/2019 0:00 |  ABC404 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  3/28/2019 0:00 |  ABC301 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  3/29/2019 0:00 |  ABC422 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  4/23/2019 0:00 |  ABC303 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  4/23/2019 0:00 |  ABC453 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  7/11/2019 0:00 |  ABC382 |     1    |
| DEW361 | 10/25/2018 0:00 |  ABC498 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  1/25/2019 0:00 |  ABC398 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  1/25/2019 0:00 |  ABC333 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  6/27/2019 0:00 |  ABC485 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  7/11/2019 0:00 |  ABC371 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  7/18/2019 0:00 |  ABC313 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  8/6/2019 0:00  |  ABC497 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  8/31/2018 0:00 |  ABC307 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/4/2018 0:00  |  ABC406 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/7/2018 0:00  |  ABC440 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/7/2018 0:00  |  ABC486 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  9/8/2018 0:00  |  ABC413 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/8/2018 0:00  |  ABC417 |     2    |
| DEW361 | 10/26/2018 0:00 |  ABC317 |     1    |
| DEW361 | 10/26/2018 0:00 |  ABC418 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/8/2018 0:00  |  ABC411 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  10/2/2018 0:00 |  ABC393 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  10/2/2018 0:00 |  ABC313 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  10/2/2018 0:00 |  ABC366 |     3    |
| DEW361 | 10/22/2018 0:00 |  ABC367 |     1    |
| DEW361 | 10/24/2018 0:00 |  ABC425 |     1    |
| DEW361 | 10/11/2018 0:00 |  ABC459 |     1    |
| DEW361 | 10/11/2018 0:00 |  ABC415 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  8/30/2018 0:00 |  ABC346 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/10/2018 0:00 |  ABC440 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/11/2018 0:00 |  ABC497 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/12/2018 0:00 |  ABC381 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/12/2018 0:00 |  ABC469 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  9/12/2018 0:00 |  ABC416 |     3    |
| DEW361 |  9/6/2018 0:00  |  ABC306 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  1/25/2019 0:00 |  ABC410 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  4/12/2019 0:00 |  ABC321 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  5/22/2019 0:00 |  ABC431 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  6/12/2019 0:00 |  ABC474 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  6/12/2019 0:00 |  ABC307 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  7/25/2019 0:00 |  ABC493 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  7/25/2019 0:00 |  ABC306 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  7/30/2019 0:00 |  ABC362 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/4/2018 0:00  |  ABC377 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/4/2018 0:00  |  ABC478 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  9/4/2018 0:00  |  ABC486 |     3    |
| DEW361 |  9/4/2018 0:00  |  ABC360 |     4    |
| DEW361 |  10/9/2018 0:00 |  ABC386 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  8/29/2018 0:00 |  ABC479 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/11/2018 0:00 |  ABC308 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/12/2018 0:00 |  ABC469 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/12/2018 0:00 |  ABC343 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/4/2018 0:00  |  ABC383 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/5/2018 0:00  |  ABC313 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/7/2018 0:00  |  ABC461 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/7/2018 0:00  |  ABC384 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  8/28/2018 0:00 |  ABC371 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  10/4/2018 0:00 |  ABC411 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  1/28/2019 0:00 |  ABC409 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  1/28/2019 0:00 |  ABC372 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  2/26/2019 0:00 |  ABC370 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/17/2018 0:00 |  ABC393 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/17/2018 0:00 |  ABC471 |     2    |
| DEW361 |  9/17/2018 0:00 |  ABC339 |     3    |
| DEW361 |  9/17/2018 0:00 |  ABC410 |     4    |
| DEW361 |  10/3/2018 0:00 |  ABC420 |     1    |
| DEW361 | 12/14/2018 0:00 |  ABC401 |     1    |
| DEW361 | 11/24/2018 0:00 |  ABC301 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  12/3/2018 0:00 |  ABC423 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  1/15/2019 0:00 |  ABC362 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  1/20/2019 0:00 |  ABC380 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  1/29/2019 0:00 |  ABC494 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  3/11/2019 0:00 |  ABC441 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  3/11/2019 0:00 |  ABC377 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/13/2018 0:00 |  ABC466 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/20/2018 0:00 |  ABC332 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/13/2018 0:00 |  ABC365 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  9/24/2018 0:00 |  ABC326 |     1    |
| DEW361 |  10/9/2018 0:00 |  ABC338 |     1    |
```

I am trying to create a box and whisker plot that will show something like the following:
[image]

I thought I got pretty close with the following:
[image]

However, I get the message that I cannot use a box and whisker plot with a pivot table. I then tried to create one manually and got:
[image]

And that clearly isn't correct. **How can I manipulate my current data to get a box and whisker plot as desired?**

NOTE - I am not adverse to doing this in VBA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Excel Plots not displaying correctly](https://superuser.com/questions/1476624/ms-excel-plots-not-displaying-correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I arranged my pivot table slightly differently, using the Tabular layout and repeating all labels (below left). I constructed a table that linked to the pivot data (below center). Then I selected the column of monthly occurrences and inserted a box plot (below right).

[image: Microsoft Excel Built-In Box Plot]

I have a box plot feature in a commercial Excel charting add-in, which is more flexible than Microsoft's version. First of all, it looks better. Also, it's easier to select options right on the worksheet, it displays various statistical calculations, and it's more readily configurable than the one above. If you're interested, there's a link in [my profile](https://superuser.com/users/95825/jon-peltier?tab=profile).

[image: Peltier Tech Box Plot]